# Differences between tick and quote as jump to mark

Tags: key-bindings

I wanted to map <kbd>'</kbd> to <kbd>"</kbd> because I think both <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd> does the same thing. But I don't want to shadow anything without knowing properly. So, any differences between <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>'</kbd> jumps to the start of a line where the mark is set, whereas <kbd>`</kbd> jumps directly to the specific character.

Personally, I find that I use <kbd>'</kbd> far more frequently than <kbd>`</kbd>, in part because it's easier to reach, but mostly because it means I don't have to care (or try to remember) precisely where within the line I set marks.

Comment: As documented in the first lines of [`:h mark-motions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#mark-motions)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember reading it. That's why I started using tick instead of quote in the first place. But it's not that important for me, so I forgot.